# How to reduce N-th highest salary query complexity in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, time-complexity

I think sorting salary table data in `desc` and putting `limit` and `offset` like below query will give you result but sorting thousands of records will affect the performance also.

`select salary from employee order by salary desc limit (n-1), 1;`

So my question is how can I reduce the complexity here? Please help.

Comment: if salary is indexed engine wouldn't have to sort (it already would be); engine just starts at the last index.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` implies sorting.  However, depending on the rest of the query and the available indexes, it *may* be possible for the Optimizer to skip the sort.  (When ordering matters, use `ORDER BY` and let the Optimizer eliminate it when it can.)

`OFFSET` (the first number in a `LIMIT` with two numbers) is implemented by fetching all those rows and tossing them.  Afterwards, the fetches the `LIMIT` rows ("1" in your case) to actually deliver to you.  That is, `OFFSET` is not cheap and is not helped by an index.

If you need the 100th row of a list, based on some sort order, your query is optimal.  Sorting "thousands" of rows is usually not a problem.  ("Billions" would be a problem.)

A common mistake is to "paginate" using `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT  0, 10  -- page 1
SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 10, 10  -- page 2
SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 20, 10  -- page 3
(etc)
```

This is "quadratic" performance.  That is, not good.

If the sort cannot be avoided, then *each* of those queries will read the entire dataset.

If the Optimizer can use an index to avoid the sort, then the first query reads 10 rows; the second reads 20, then 30, etc.  Notice how it gets slower and slower.

(The optimization of pagination involves "remembering where you left off".)

Is your query really about salaries and fetching only the nth and only doing it once?  Or is that an over-simplification of the real use case?  There may be other tricks if you show us the 'real' query.

Big-O:

Sort N rows: O(N*log N)
OFFSET N: O(N)
LIMIT N: O(N)
SELECT N rows:  O(N)
Paginate all pages (P items per page) using Offset, worst case:  O((N/P)*N*logN)
Pagination with 'left off':  O(N)